# java ee System.loadLibrary

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface, jersey

I have Jersey Restful service with Eclipse and I need to load JNI library.

For normal java application, I could place the *.dylib file in project root directory and do the following:

```
System.loadLibrary("FaceDetection");
```

Here if my source code of project is: /path/to/project/src/..., then I'll put FaceDetection.dylib at /path/to/project/FaceDetection.dylib.

However, in Jersey (I'm not sure if this is Jersey thing or Java EE), if I put it the same place, it can't find this library.

What I'm doing so far is to manually place this library in System's Java library, but this is not ideal and hard to move around. Is there a way to place this library under project's folder and load in Restful Service?

Comment: You should specify the java.library.path on the command line by using the -D option `-Djava.library.path=/path/to/project/`

Comment: @lvan Can you be a little bit more specific? I tried but doesn't work.